# Dependency issues with react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I have been attempting to clone code from multiple repositories on GitHub, but each time I do so, I encounter numerous dependency issues. While I am relatively new to React Native, I do work as a front-end web developer with React. Typically, running `npm i` resolves such issues, but in the case of React Native, it's not as straightforward. I consistently receive errors indicating that something is missing within the `node_modules` directory. For instance, I might encounter errors like:

```
None of these files exist:
  * node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\DatePicker\DatePickerIOS(.native|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json)      
  * node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\DatePicker\DatePickerIOS\index(.native|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json)
import typeof DatePickerIOS from './Libraries/Components/DatePicker/DatePickerIOS';
```

And for the love of God, this is very difficult to find a solution for because of the multitude of approaches to developing mobile apps. For instance, I am using Expo, but all the fixes I found were intended for Xcode.

Is there any method to manage the cloning of repositories from GitHub without encountering a multitude of dependency issues?

Comment: Is it you or an external package that is importing DatePicker? DatePicker was deprecated/exported to its own external library. If you are the one importing it just install and use [datepicker](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/date-time-picker/). If its an external library you may want to use a different one, as DatePicker has been deprecated for a while which means that library really isnt being maintained

Comment: @PhantomSpooks thanks for the answer - yeah this is from old youtube tutorials.. I assume they used old libraries.. to fix it I just followed along sadly - because I'm not yet at a level where I feel comfortable debugging everything

I leaned that I need to use the -c flag after installing dependencies (which I was not aware of before) to clear cache, and it helped me with some dependency errors.. thank you for taking the time to answer